# Why is my app dying after invoking popToRootViewControllerAnimated?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

After I call

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

I can see in the root view controller that viewWillAppear enters and exits.

Then I see a message on the console that reads

```
*** -[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x4a9eab0
```

And then my app abruptly terminates.

I don't think it's in any of my methods when this occurs.

Note that before I pop to the root controller I have the code put up an alarm and I can see the root view underneath the alarm and as soon as I press the "cancel" button, my root view disappears and the iphone simulator displays the home page instead of leaving my root view showing.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking at the answer of this question.
Just trace what's happening in each controller's dealloc method.
(by each, I mean all controllers pushed to the navigation controller).
There is probably a release that shouldn't be there (on a object you have not allocated)

Answer (score 0):

yes same pretty much as Stephane, I had an issue where i was releasing a viewController in code as to which i later referenced, this had pretty much the same effect,however, would some times tell me :

```
*** -[NSCFType popToRootViewController]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x4a9eab0
```

Check for anything you are releasing.